# Cannot resolve dependency class file in maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am facing issue in importing class files from dependency project though the dependency jar is downloaded in the Maven dependencies path in STS IDE.

I have created 2 maven spring-boot projects where one is app and other is database. I have installed database maven project in local maven repositories using maven install commands.

When I use the database project as dependency in app project, maven is downloading the dependency of database project jar and placing it in Maven dependencies path. But I could not import the class files from database project jar. It says "class name cannot be resolved" error.

I have tried importing the database project in STS IDE. The app project could able to load classes only if database project is opened in the workspace. If I close the database project, then I am getting error in importing class files in app project.

I am using below "spring-boot-maven-plugin" plugin to build database jar.

I would expect to import the database project classes in the app project but I am getting import errors.

Kindly advice me on fixing this issue.

Comment: I am no spring expert, but are you sure that a spring boot project is meant to work as a dependency? Wouldn't it be better to use a "normal" jar.

Comment: Remove <scope> parameter if you are providing it.

Comment: @shubham Jain - I have not given any scope in the dependency. It was with default compile scope

Comment: @JF Meier - The dependent application has some usage with respect to spring-boot, so it will not give expected output with normal jar.

Comment: I am not sure, but it may be the case that your spring boot jar has a different internal structure and therefore the classes cannot be found by Maven.